# What's the MVC3 Razor equivalent of Page.Form.DefaultFocus?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

If I wanted to conditionally set which field should have focus using ASP.NET WebForms, I would set [Page.Form.DefaultFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultfocus%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). What is the MVC3 Razor way to do the same?

Background: I have a login page. Sometimes the username field is automatically filled in, sometimes it's blank. If the username field is blank, I want it to have the focus. If the username field is filled in, I want focus on the password field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var username = $('#Username'); // TODO: adjust selector if necessary
    if (username.val() === '') {
        username.focus();
    } else {
        $('#Password').focus(); // TODO: adjust selector if necessary
    }
});
```

Comment: @SergioTapia, of course that client side is the way to go. It's the only way.